# nginx rewrite with proxy_pass returns 404

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule combining with `proxy_pass` yet I keep getting `404` response code.

Nginx is a reverse proxy to a nodejs and app and I would like to point a specific path to a longer path without exposing it, here is my current server block:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    keepalive 128;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/health$ /app/custom/path/health break; <-- this returns 404
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "http";
        proxy_pass http://backend$request_uri;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try using `proxy_pass http://backend;`

Comment: `rewrite` directive changes the `$uri` internal nginx variable, not the `$request_uri` one. As already said, using `proxy_pass http://backend;` should be enough, if not, try `proxy_pass http://backend$uri?$args;`.

Comment: @IvanShatsky but then won't it break other calls which are not /health ?

Comment: No, when you specify only the backend hostname or upstream name (like `proxy_pass http://backend;`) your request URI and query arguments should be passed to backend as they are appeared in the request (unless you modify them via `rewrite` or `set $args something`).